# From POST form saving the record to the mysql db

Tags: php, mysql

I have done this many time to get the form POST and saving in a mysql db. I have a form with some data and when i save the button the data should be saved to another table. I have some 350 records to show in the form and when i save it, it should write to another table. But when the records are saved to another table its just saving some 63 records to another table from the form where as the actual record numbers is above 250 records.

My save.php file is as follows:

```
$size = count($_POST['sl']);
$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
    $sl= $_POST['sl'][$i];
    $item_id= $_POST['item_id'][$i];
    $item_name= $_POST['item_name'][$i];

    $query = "INSERT INTO anothertable SET slno = '$sl',item_name = '$item_name',item_id = 
'$item_id' ";
mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");

++$i;
}
```

Is this script fine? Or Am i making any mistake?

The Form script is posted below:

```
  <?php

   echo "<form name='cart' method='post' action='price_add_save.php?supplier_name=$supplier_name_enc&tender_id=$tender_id' >";?>

  $sql= "(SELECT item_name, item_id, tender_id, slno FROM tender_items WHERE tender_id=$tender_id) order by slno";
  $result = mysql_query($sql) or die($sql."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());

    $i = 0;

     while ($list5 = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {


        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td width='4%'><input size='1' type='text' id='sl[$i]' name='sl[$i]' value='{$list5['slno']}' readonly/></td>";
        echo "<td width='10%' id='addinput'><input type='text' size='15' name='item_name[$i]' placeholder='{$list5['item_name']}' value='{$list5['item_name']}'></td>";
        echo "<td width='3%'><input size='2' class='item_id' type='text' name='item_id[$i]' value='{$list5['item_id']}' readonly/></td>";

        ++$i;
    }   
    echo '<input type="submit" value="--Save Data--" />';
   ?>
```

Comment: is the "slno" ur primary key

Comment: No its not.. my serial  number is id.

Comment: Your insert query is wrong. You can't use SET in INSERT statement

Comment: @EdwinAlex: but its not invalid.

Comment: ok i will rework on this. But do i have to use For Loop or While Loop here?

Comment: you want to insert or update??? if really insert than what is the result of echo count($_POST['sl']); ??? is it 250???

Comment: @devpro: Though it is valid, it is not a good practice.

Comment: i know set will work with insert..

Comment: @devpro. I want to insert records

Comment: @EdwinAlex: agreed, not good practice. :)

Comment: @devpro...count($_POST['sl']);  should actually show 250 but here its showing 63 only. That's the main problem iam facing.

Comment: This fact this script is not working is in fact a very good thing. I would recommend reading up on mysqli/PDO and bind vars. As it stands this script is very dangerous and I would not ever put this on a live server.

Comment: that means, your query is working fine, problem in other section.. right

Comment: @devpro. yes absolutely. Even i tried to just read the records...even its showing is 63 records...

Comment: You should really show us how the form is getting generated to input 250 values?

Comment: <input type="text" name="sl[]"> maybe your form something like that, is it really contains 250 inputs??

Comment: @Edwin..That form is taking data from another db and its showing fine. Its showing all the records. But when i save the form values to another table its just 63 records. Do u want me to post the form generated page?

Comment: Yes. Show us `<form>` code too..

Comment: @devpro..yes exactly...Its awhile loop and its showing the form..and it is showing all 250 records

Comment: i will add the form code also..

Comment: I think you need to check post_max_size in your .ini settings..

Comment: chk post_max_size and upload_max_filesize ? how much allowed?? by using phpinfo();

Comment: Why you left `$i` in `name='item_id[]'` ?

Comment: post_max_size is 64 M and upload_max_filesize is 16 M

Comment: @ nana.. oh that's a mistake

Comment: i have edited the question with Form page also..

Comment: @NanaPartykar..i changed to item_id[$i], still problem persists. I want to know why my for While Loop count ($size = count($_POST['sl']);)is showing to just 62 records?

Comment: changing on item_id[$i] will not effect any thing because u are already start from $i = 0

Comment: Change `$size = count($_POST['sl']);` to `$size = sizeof($_POST['sl']);` and tell me the output please

Comment: @ Nana..Let me try..

Comment: @devpro. yes that's true

Comment: @NanaPartykar..No still the count is 62 only...

Comment: well, run your query and chk how many counts are fetching.. (SELECT count(*) FROM tender_items WHERE tender_id=$tender_id) order by slno in PHP MYADMIN

Comment: Really no idea on this. May be i need to recode the entire section..?

Comment: @devpro. i queried it, and the count its showing is 250.

Comment: and if you r looking for second solution, than just tell me, why r u using two loops, if value of input box, is there any need of inputs or forms.

Comment: The form page is fetching the records from different table, say tender_items and its showing all the records. And when i submit the form, its writing the values to a different table (say Table 2). Field names are all same in two tables... That's what iam trying to do

Comment: @devpro. Can u pls suggest me a second solution

Comment: Do NOT use `MySQL_*` it has been removed and will not work anymore. Use `PDO` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or `MySQLi` [link](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) instead.

Comment: @Tom. intially i did in mysqli only..when i had this problem, i just tried in mysql..once this is solved, i will change to mysqli. Thankx

Comment: @SanjuMenon No, change it now, this is a really bad practice.

Comment: @SanjuMenon Your update query doesn't define a WHERE, so it just updates everything to the value you want it to.

Comment: ok, i will share u the second solution...

Comment: this is one time activity???

Comment: Just declare `$tender_id` in this query and execute it. It will insert into `anothertable`. **Query :**
`INSERT INTO anothertable (slno,item_name,item_id) SELECT slno, item_name, item_id  FROM tender_items WHERE tender_id=$tender_id;`

Comment: @devpro.. its is not one time activity in terms of process.

Comment: @NanaPartykar. i cant directly insert from one table to another because in the forms page there are some calculations taking place with jquery and the form result only i can insert to another table.

Comment: @devpro. Really thank you for your time and help.

Comment: *good sound, you have solved your problem.

Comment: Finally you got your answer. I am seeing you since last week that you were tensed regarding your project. Well done @SanjuMenon.

Comment: @NanaPartykar. Yeah working on a project.. Just one problem solved..Like this need to solve many problems..:) Hoping for the best. Thank you so much for your help and support.

Answer (score 2):

It was basically an issue with `max_input_vars` in **php.ini**. I changed from `1000` to `5000`..its working fine now. Thank you all..